# retrieve a random row for a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with following columns

```
1. ID
2. UserID
3. ImageUrl
```

I want retrieve a random ImageUrl for each UserID. For example, there 4 rows in the table

```
 1 12251 Winter.jpg
 2 12251 Summer.jpg 
 3 33333 Fall.jpg
 4 33333 Spring.jpg
```

and the query retrieve the following rows

```
 1 12251 Winter.jpg
 4 33333 Spring.jpg
```

Comment: Just to make sure, do you mean truly random (ie every reload, different picture) or just "any picture will do" per user?

Comment: just any picture for each users but if it is truly random is better

Comment: are `12251` and `33333` userid ? i'm a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select userid,picture from
(
select userid, picture, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by userid order by newid()) rn 
from yourtable
) v
where rn =1
order by xtype
```